# property 'responseSerializer' not found on object of type 'AFDownloadRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, vine

so i have this app, and i cannot work out why i am unable to run my app. Can anyone explain why this keeps happening?

Here is the section of code its in.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a11i04ogoze77qa/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-01%20at%2009.42.58.png

Here is the source code f you wanna take a look
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpvhnrup92fhmt5/motikyapp-master.zip

Thanks 
Jake

Comment: Please copy/paste the (relevant!) code and the exact error message into the question itself.

Comment: Are you sure your 'self' class has 'responseSerializer' property?

Comment: What do you mean by that? sorry

Comment: just comment out those 2 line (if … return) and it will run and download your stuff